# Nativescript and angular 2 app breaks when making http calls

Tags: angular2-http, angular2-nativescript

On updating to tns core module 2.2.0 and angular rc4 (officially released version by telerik), My app can no longer make http calls to a server, I keep getting this error

```
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onClick failed

EXCEPTION: Error in /data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/pages/login/login.html:5:75
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error: not implemented
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: not implemented
    at NativeScriptDomAdapter.Parse5DomAdapter.getCookie (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/platform-server/src/parse5_adapter.js:619:68)
    at CookieXSRFStrategy.configureRequest (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js:150:82)
    at XHRBackend.createConnection (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js:165:28)
    at httpRequest (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/src/http.js:22:20)
    at Http.post (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/http/src/http.js:78:16)
    at UserService.signin (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/shared/services/user.service.js:13:27)
    at LoginComponent.login (/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/pages/login/login.component.js:31:27)
    at DebugAppView._View_LoginComponent0._handle_tap_8_0 (LoginComponent.template.js:355:28)
    at /data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:375:24
    at /data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js:204:26
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js, line: 365, column: 16

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js', line: 365, column: 17
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js', line: 378, column: 23
    Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js', line: 204, column: 26
    Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js', line: 290, column: 29
    Frame: function:'NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js', line: 53, column: 41
    Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js', line: 289, column: 35
    Frame: function:'Zone.run', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js', line: 183, column: 44
    Frame: function:'NgZoneImpl.runInner', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js', line: 84, column: 71
    Frame: function:'NgZone.run', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js', line: 235, column: 66
    Frame: function:'zonedCallback', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/renderer.js', line: 203, column: 24
    Frame: function:'Observable.notify', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 174, column: 23
    Frame: function:'Observable._emit', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/data/observable/observable.js', line: 193, column: 18
    Frame: function:'_android.setOnClickListener.android.view.View.OnClickListener.onClick', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.EatSafe/files/app/tns_modules/ui/button/button.js', line: 33, column: 32


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:862)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:727)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:713)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:694)
    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:684)
    at com.tns.gen.android.view.View_OnClickListener.onClick(View_OnClickListener.java:11)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21209)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I have been trying to look online for a release log of the update to see if there are any breaking changes, but to no avail. does anyone have any pointers on how to make http calls with the new nativescript angular updates?

Thank you

Comment: I do not know if this will actually solve your problem but there is an open issue here on github:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/397

Comment: Thank you, I found the issue and used the suggestion by Nathan and it worked. You have to bootstrap NS_HTTP_PROVIDERS in main.ts, and make sure you set the version of nativescript-angular to 'next' in both package.json files. npm install and build. that should fix it.

Comment: Which is the "other" package.json file? The one in the `app` folder?

Comment: yes, the one in the `app` folder

Answer (score 2):

I got this fixed by importing in `app.moudle.ts` the following

```
import {NativeScriptHttpModule} from 'nativescript-angular/http';
```

And then

```
 imports: [NativeScriptHttpModule]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this code in your main.ts file

```
import {Parse5DomAdapter} from '@angular/platform-server/src/parse5_adapter';

(<any>Parse5DomAdapter).prototype.getCookie = function (name) { return null; };
```